# Can not pull or push to repo using Sourcetree

Tags: git, bitbucket, commit, atlassian-sourcetree, pull

I am getting the following error when I try to pull the changes from the repo using Sourcetree:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks push -v --tags origin master:master
Pushing to git@bitbucket.org:doesnotmatter.git
repository access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Completed with errors, see above.
```

I checked that ssh keys are setup correctly in both bitbucket and sourcetree. I checked that I have an access to the repository.

What else may I check?

Thank you.

Here is what I see when I run `git remote show origin`:
[image]

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@bitbucket.org:doesnotmatter.git
  Push  URL: git@bitbucket.org:doesnotmatter.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    GAM-478 tracked
    master  tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

Here is what I see when I run `ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org`:

[image]

```
oobarbazanoo@LAPTOP-CQEVT11F MINGW64 /c/Projects/WebStorm/doesnotmatter (master)
$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
logged in as yrslvtrfmvdoesnotmatter.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

Here is what I see after running `git fetch origin`:
[image]
(i.e. just nothing).

Comment: Check `git remote show origin`

Comment: Do you have network access? Check if you can [connect per SSH](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/permission-denied-publickey-302811860.html).

Comment: Thank you everyone! I updated my question.

Comment: And running `git fetch origin` from that same shell does not work?

Comment: @poke, updated my question, thank you.

Comment: So fetching from the console appears to work. In that case, pushing should also work. If it does, that means that SourceTree isn't picking up the configuration.

Comment: @poke, thank you. What could I try to undertake in such a situation?

Comment: I don’t have SourceTree myself but according to [this guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html#SetupanSSHkey-ssh3SetupSSHwithSourcetreeonWindows), SourceTree appears to use PuTTY for SSH keys instead of openssl (which is used by Git by default). So you may need to import your SSH key into PuTTYgen.